# KairosDB failed to discover other Cassandra nodes in ring with Hector client

Tags: cassandra, hector, kairosdb

I have a multi-node Casssandra cluster (2.2.6) and a separate KairosDB server (1.1.1-1). In KairosDB, I configured it with two Cassandra seed nodes and have it auto discover other Cassandra nodes in the ring.

After tuning KairosDB log level to DEBUG, I see that only those two seed nodes are in host pool (and working well). Hector discovery process failed with an NPE. At the end only these two seed nodes are used by KairosDB.

There might be a few solutions:

1. Add all nodes to kairos properties, but it's harder to maintain.
2. Custom build a new KairosDB binary to have later version of Hector 2.0.0, but I prefer to go with official releases if possible.

Do you know a way to get around this? Thanks.

```
08-04|18:54:57.755 [Hector.me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.NodeAutoDiscoverService-1] DEBUG [NodeDiscovery.java:50] - Node discovery running...
08-04|18:54:57.756 [Hector.me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.NodeAutoDiscoverService-1] DEBUG [NodeDiscovery.java:74] - using existing hosts [cassandra-seed1(172.16.109.43):9160, cassandra-seed2(172.16.108.51):9160]
08-04|18:54:57.756 [Hector.me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.NodeAutoDiscoverService-1] ERROR [NodeDiscovery.java:105] - Discovery Service failed attempt to connect CassandraHost
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.NodeDiscovery.discoverNodes(NodeDiscovery.java:79) [hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.NodeDiscovery.doAddNodes(NodeDiscovery.java:52) [hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.NodeAutoDiscoverService.doAddNodes(NodeAutoDiscoverService.java:45) [hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.NodeAutoDiscoverService$QueryRing.run(NodeAutoDiscoverService.java:51) [hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_101]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_101]
08-04|18:54:57.756 [Hector.me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.NodeAutoDiscoverService-1] DEBUG [NodeDiscovery.java:62] - Node discovery run complete.
```